# Virtual environment point to compiled tensorflow binary

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv

I recently started exploring tensorflow and to boost speed, I compiled the tf package in order to use my GPU. I would like to use these binaries in several projects.

Usually I use virtual environments to separate different python packages and I would like to continue using it. So lets say I installed tensorflow in the directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. Is there a command in virtualenv / pip that basically says "Use these binaries"?

Comment: That would be meaningless because globally installed TF will use global `site-packages`/`dist-packages` instead of your virtual env.

Comment: Yes, but besides tensorflow, I would like to use other packages as well. Are you suggesting in order to use global tf, I must globally install all other packages that I am using?

Comment: Exactly opposite — I suggest to use virtual env and install TF in it.

Comment: I tried that, and that version of tf does not use my cpu/gpu to my full extend